# SQL select query between two dates

Tags: sql, date, select, between

How do I list all movies released between `2000` and `2010`?

```
SELECT title 
FROM films 
WHERE releaseYear > 2000 && < 2010
```

or do I have to use 'between'? I'm new to this and I'm trying to learn. I've looked for similar questions here on stackoverflow, but everyone seems to give a different answer. Are there different possibilities?

Comment: WHERE releaseYear between 2000 and 2010

Comment: Or `WHERE releaseYear>=2000 and releaseYear<=2010`

Comment: So there really are different possibilities? Can I also use #2000 and #2010 then?

Comment: It's also important to note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both sides. So the comment of @PanagiotisKanavos is equivalent to the `BETWEEN` operator as used by @jarlh. These are NOT equivalent to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @HoneyBadger that's assuming that `between` means `except years 2000 and 2010`. I think that's not the case and the code is just a typo

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, unless I misunderstand you, there is no assumption, `BETWEEN` does mean including years 2000  and 2010. The OP may have made a type, but it's worth mentioning the effect to the OP.

Comment: @HoneyBadger No, it really was a typo. Thanks though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the between clause like so:

```
Where ReleaseYear between 2000 and 2010
```

Or equivalent:

```
Where ReleaseYear >=2000 and ReleaseYear <= 2010
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
SELECT title FROM films WHERE releaseYear between 2000 and 2010;
```

Tip: when you using "between" you should write smaller firstly. **between** **small value** and **bigger value**

Answer (score 0):

You could either write the condition directly with `>` and `<` operators (note that the logical "and" operator is `and` not `&&`, and that both its sides should be valid SQL conditions):

```
SELECT title FROM films WHERE releaseYear > 2000 AND releaseYear < 2010
```

Or use the `between` operator (note that the `between` operator is not exclusive, so 2011 is used instead of 2010):

```
SELECT title FROM films WHERE releaseYear BETWEEN 2000 AND 2011
```

Comment: These are not the same; `BETWEEN` is inclusive. From BOL: "BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression."

Comment: @HoneyBadger nice catch - I was not paying enough attention. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of them. But first improve your syntax such as:-

```
SELECT title 
FROM films 
WHERE releaseYear >= 2000 
AND releaseYear <= 2010;
```

or

```
SELECT title 
FROM films 
WHERE releaseYear BETWEEN 2000 AND 2010;
```

Comment: I was just telling him the logic. And i know whatever you are saying. Now see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Between' clause like

```
Select titles 
From films 
Where releaseYear between 2000 and 2010;
```

but try to avoid the following

```
Select titles 
From films 
Where releaseYear >= 2010 and releaseYear <= 2010;
```

because there is a difference in the data filteration method and causes performance issue.